# AngularJS Append new input and set it's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm creating a directive with an input skeleton like this

`<input type="hidden" data-ng-model="model['foo'][__index__]['bar']" data-ng-init="model['foo'][__index__]['bar'] = null" name="foo___index___bar">`

Whenever an action is triggered, I just get this skeleton, replace `__index__` for an integer based on the action (mostly current array position) and append it into a div.

This works perfectly, it's just a

`element.append(newInput)`

then with a  `$compile(element)(scope)` I load angular on my new elements.

The problem is that I must set a value for each newly created input, I've tried with `newInput.val(myVal)` but it doesn't work. In my scope, the new value is not set.

I could do `scope.model['foo'][__index__]['bar'] = myVal` but I can't because code should be reusable for other forms, and input names will change (that's why it's a directive).

How can achieve this?

My whole code is as follows

```
<div data-index="0" data-prototype="<input type=\"hidden\" data-ng-model=\"model['foo'][__index__]['bar']\" data-ng-init=\"model['foo'][__index__]['bar'] = null\" name=\"foo___index___bar\">"></div>
```

JS

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('ngSkeleton')
    .directive('ngSkeleton', function($log, $http, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict    : 'AE',
            require     : '?ngModel',
            scope       : {
                prototype: '@',
                index: '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                myVal = "something_in_here";
                scope.index = element.find(':input').length;
                var newInput   = angular.element(scope.prototype.replace(/__index__/ig, scope.index));
                newInput.val(myVal);
                element.append(newInput);
                scope.index++;
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Why do you have template in `data-prototype` attribute? You can use `<script id="../path/to/template.html" type="text/ng-template"> html template goes here </script>` if you want to inline it.

Comment: Because it's rendered using Twig using a Symfony2 application and I need that code in an attribute if we need to use it with jQuery only... And as I said, form names and field names changes depending on where you are (Symfony2) so it's impossible to use a static template for everything...